# Best way to separate arrays of objects made of multiple loose objects?

Tags: modifiers, collections

The "arch" I have selected is composed of multiple loose objects.
I join them with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to make 1 object, so I can then add 2 array modifiers to quickly replicate/position more of them.
I then want to separate each "arch" so I can assign them to their collections and then "separate loose parts", giving me back control of their individual "bricks".[image]
The problem I have is once I have applied the arrays, all 8 "arches" are joined together as a single object, making then separating them an awkward task.
Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have Merge turned on in your array modifier settings, seperating them should be a breeze! <kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>

Hover your mouse over one of the arches, hit <kbd>L</kbd> then hit <kbd>P</kbd> repeat

[image]

Comment: This wont work in my case. In your scenario you are making an array from a single object and then separating them out. What I'm looking to do is essentially stack individual bricks to make a structure, then join them so i can array the structure, then quickly separate them first into the arches, then back into bricks.

Comment: Right... That's a much bigger task! I misunderstood the question...